# How to update activity after image upload in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, uiimageview

I have an activity where the user can update some data related to his profile (for example, his name) and he can also upload a new profile image.

After the update operation, the user is redirected to a new activity.
The problem is that when the user comes back to his profile activity, the showed image is still the old one and not the new one while the name updated correctly.

In order to see the new profile image, the user needs to close the app and open is again.

How can I solve this problem?
I use a function updateInfo(), but it seems to not work as I would like.

Can you help me, please?

```
    public class ProfileActivity extends BaseActivity implements ProfileView {

    @BindView(R.id.avatar)
    ImageView p_avatar;
    @BindView(R.id.ib_back)
    ImageButton ibBack;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_title)
    TextView txtTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.ib_right)
    ImageButton ibRight;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.et_fullname)
    EditText etFullname;
    @BindView(R.id.et_email)
    EditText etEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_update)
    Button btnUpdate;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_logout)
    TextView txtLogout;
    @BindView(R.id.ll_main)
    LinearLayout llMain;

    private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";
    private String userName = null, userEmail = null;
    private ProfilePresenter profilePresenter;
    private Dialog dialog;
    Bitmap FixBitmap;
    Bitmap bitmap_to_save;
    ImageView ShowSelectedImage;
    String converted_img;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    byte[] byteArray ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        init_view();
        upDateInfo();
    }


    private void init_view() {
        txtTitle.setText(R.string.profileActivity_title);
        ibRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_edit);

        dialog = commonUtils.createCustomLoader(ProfileActivity.this, false);
        profilePresenter = new ProfilePresenterImpl(this);

        upDateInfo();
    }

    private void upDateInfo() {
        if (Conts.USERINFO != null) {
            String subName = firstTwoChar(Conts.USERINFO.getName());
           // Picasso.get().load("http://www.server.com/uploads/avatars/73.png").transform(transformation).into(p_avatar);

            final int radius = 30;
            final int margin = 1;
            final RoundedCornersTransformation transformation = new RoundedCornersTransformation(radius, margin);
            Picasso.get().load("http://www.server.com/uploads/avatars/"+Conts.USERINFO.getId()).transform(transformation).into(p_avatar);


            etFullname.setText(Conts.USERINFO.getName().toLowerCase());
            etFullname.setEnabled(false);
            etEmail.setText(Conts.USERINFO.getEmail());
            etEmail.setEnabled(false);
            btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.ib_back, R.id.ib_right, R.id.btn_update, R.id.txt_logout, R.id.avatar})
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.ib_back:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            case R.id.ib_right:
                etFullname.setEnabled(true);
                etFullname.setSelection(etFullname.getText().toString().length());
                btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "validate ID: " + Conts.USERINFO.getId());
                return;
            case R.id.avatar:
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 1);
                return;
            case R.id.btn_update:
                if (validate()) {
                    if (!commonUtils.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    profilePresenter.dataListAPI(Conts.USERINFO.getId(), userName, Conts.USERINFO.getEmail(), converted_img);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.txt_logout:
                get_dialog();
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {

        super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);

        if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = I.getData();

            try {

                FixBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                bitmap_to_save = scaleBitmapAndKeepRation(FixBitmap, 320, 320);


                RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap_to_save);
                final float roundPx = (float) bitmap_to_save.getWidth() * 0.15f;
                roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(roundPx);
                roundedBitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true);
                p_avatar.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);


                bitmap_to_save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

                byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                converted_img = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT); // this is the image string to send to the server!


            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    public static Bitmap scaleBitmapAndKeepRation(Bitmap TargetBmp, int reqHeightInPixels, int reqWidthInPixels)
    {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, TargetBmp.getWidth(), TargetBmp.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, reqWidthInPixels, reqHeightInPixels), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(TargetBmp, 0, 0, TargetBmp.getWidth(), TargetBmp.getHeight(), m, true);
        return scaledBitmap;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void get_dialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_logout, null);

        builder.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        alertDialog.show();

        TextView txtyes, txtno;

        txtyes = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_yes);
        txtno = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_no);

        txtyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                sharedPref.setBoolean(Conts.IsLogin, false);
                sharedPref.clearAllPref();
                Conts.USERINFO = null;

                Intent iLogin = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                iLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(iLogin);
            }
        });

        txtno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    public String firstTwoChar(String str) {
        return str.length() < 2 ? str : str.substring(0, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void showLoader() {
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void hideLoader() {
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void showError(String msg) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(llMain, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //  nothing anything
                    }
                });

        snackbar.show();

        // Changing message text color
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

        // Changing action button text color
        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        snackbar.show();
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContextAppp() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPress() {

    }

    @Override
    public void successResponse(Data data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(data.getId(), data.getName(), data.getEmail());
            Conts.USERINFO = userInfo;
            String userinfo = gson.toJson(Conts.USERINFO, UserInfo.class);
            sharedPref.setDataInPref(Conts.UserInfo, userinfo);

            startActivity(getIntent());
            Intent iPlace = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, AddPlaceActivity.class);
            iPlace.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(iPlace);



        }
    }

    @Override
    public void errorResponce(String msg) {
        if (msg != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean validate() {
        commonUtils.hideKeyboard(this);

        if (etFullname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Fullname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (etFullname.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Minimum 3 character require", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (etFullname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 30) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Maximum 30 character require", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        /*else if (etEmail.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!validation.checkEmail(etEmail)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter valid Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
*/
        if (!etFullname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && etFullname.getText().toString().trim().length() > 2 && etFullname.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 30) {
            userName = etFullname.getText().toString().trim();
        } else {
            userName = null;
        }

        /*if (!etEmail.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && validation.checkEmail(etEmail)) {
            userEmail = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        } else {
            userEmail = null;
        }
*/
        if (userName != null /*&& userEmail != null*/) {
            Log.d(TAG, "validate: " + userName);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you pretty sure, that the uploading of newly selected image was success? I'm just thinking, because the code looks correct, so this is only thing. Or try to disable caching function for Picasso .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE) or even use different Image library like Glide, UIL and so on...

Comment: Yes, the new image is uploaded on the server, I checked it. When the user close and open again the app, he can see the new image without problems.

Comment: And the cache policy? Or different library? I think, that it will be the easiest path how to resolve the problem.

Comment: It's my first time with Picasso library, how can I force Picasso to clear the cache? where should I put the instruction?

Comment: The code for picass: Picasso
.get()
.load("http://www.server.com/uploads/avatars/"+Conts.USERINFO.getId())
.transform(transformation)
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.into(p_avatar);

Comment: Do the new image has the same url after being changed? `Glide` and possibly `Picasso` use the load mode (url) as the cache key.

Comment: Thank you, jantursky! You solved my problem! It was related to the cache problem! Post an answer and I will vote it.
@Tam: thanks also to your support! The image has the same url, but it was related to the cache.

Comment: Yes it's cache problem because the url is the cache key, new image has the same url so it uses the cache first. Disable cache, or keep caching with more complex cache policy. Anyway, glad you can fix it

Answer (score 1):

When you turn back to your profile activity your application's task stack is bringing back your profile activity which is already in memory. So you should inform your profile activity that it was updated. In the onStart callback of your profile activity check if it is updated. If so load the new image. In short put your upDateInfo() method inside onStart().

Answer (score 1):

After you update the information, in `callback` method `onResponse` you need to call `updateInfo()` to make an update on your UI after update of information is successfully finished. Make sure you provide new values from server especially to `static` variables because they will keep values as long as app is live. If you don't update them with new values they will keep old ones.

Currently on that way you are trying to update informations only in `onCreate()` which is called when `Activity` needs to be created. In this scenario it is when you exit and enter app again only by pressing `Back` button while on `Home` button it will not work as well until app is destroyed by OS.

You could also use `onResume` method which is called after `Activity` is returned from pause and that will happen when you create a new `Activity` upon already exiting one.